# error in installing pyradar package on python3.6 using pip

Tags: python-3.x

```
C:\Program Files\Python36-32\Scripts>pip install pyradar
Collecting pyradar
  Using cached pyradar-0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Ghazal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jcyxj24c\pyradar\setup.
py", line 85
        print "\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(msg, limits,
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Ghazal\A
ppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jcyxj24c\pyradar\
```

Comment: are you sure that pyradar is available for python3.x ?

Comment: No. it is available for python 2.7

Comment: you are running pip from python3 so it is giving you error. You have to use pip2 (pip python2) to install successfully

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Pyradar is not available for python3. Instead of python3 it can be used with python2.

Refs: [docs](https://github.com/PyRadar/pyradar/blob/master/setup.py)